# Implementing a Selector on an InQueue

Tags: ibm-mq

My current setup consists of one queue, the InQueue, called "QONE". QONE then has 6 other queues that it sends messages to. Each of these subsequent queues has a selector on it which accepts messages based on a regular expression.

There is a situation where I want to ignore a message completely. Meaning, when QONE gets a message matching a specific pattern, do not send the message down to any other queue. Instead we want to disregard the message.

Can I put a selector on QONE which will serve to filter out the unwanted messages? For example, if the unwanted message is sent to QONE it will know not to send it down to any subsequent queues based on the selector's pattern.

I want to avoid adding to the selectors of the subsequent queues, though I know this is an option. I'd rather remove the message at the root rather then the downstream queues. Thank you.

Comment: A queue doesn't send messages anywhere, it stores them. Presumably you have an application getting message from QONE and putting them to one of the other 6 queues?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Voted up Morag's answer as that's the approach you should be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way of implementing this would be to ensure the application on QONE, which forwards the messages on to the other six queues, reads all the messages and by looking at each message, either forwards it, or does whatever should happen to these messages you want to ignore (are you planning to simply discard them, or place them on a side queue out of the way?). If the application on QONE correctly only forwards the required messages, then no selectors are required on the downstream queues.